# How to declare this column with SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I have a MySQL table where one of the columns is a decimal. It is created with the following parameters:

```
 `ratio` decimal(5,3) DEFAULT NULL,
```

So far the sample scripts I'm putting together is super dumbed down.

```
import sys 
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String

Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = Session()
Base = declarative_base()

class DailyProjections(Base):
  __tablename__ = 'daily_projections'

  id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
  name = Column(String(100))
```

How do I declare the ratio column here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [docs](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/core/type_basics.html#sqlalchemy.types.Numeric):

> The Numeric type is designed to receive data from a database type that
>   is explicitly known to be a decimal type (e.g. DECIMAL, NUMERIC,
>   others) and not a floating point type (e.g. FLOAT, REAL, others).

So you declare it like so:

```
ratio = Column(Numeric(5, 3), nullable=True)
```